# Facebook SDK publish as a separate class

Tags: android, facebook

I have created a class with the following method from sample code

```
private void publishStory() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {

            // Check for publish permissions    
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                    pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                            .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                    return;
               }

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
            postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
            postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
            postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                               .getGraphObject()
                                               .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG,
                            "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                             .getApplicationContext(),
                             error.getErrorMessage(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                                 .getApplicationContext(), 
                                 postId,
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                                  HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }
    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I sometimes get the following error on the permission line-

```
( session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);)
```

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.

All I have in this class is the above method. I call it when I want to publish something to Facebook. The code for the `Login` is in a different class and not called.

Question really is why am I getting this error? Do I need to add some of the `UiLifecycleHelper` code into the class, and if so, which parts?

Would like to keep this as a seperate class but am I going down the wrong route and should just build into the Activity class that is doing the publish

Thanks for your time

Comment: I've read this twice now and I don't know what you're trying to achieve, sorry.

Comment: Let me see if I can rewrite it

Comment: Where do you call the publishStory method? The issue here is that you're making a request to get publish permissions WHILE there's another request (probably to open the session) going on. You need to move the caller of publishStory into the callback for the session open, or somewhere else where you know the session is already open and ready for use.

Comment: Are you following Facebook's advice closely, or doing your own thing? Facbook allows you to pass a listener object which is called as the user login progresses. Listen for when the session is open before anything else.